# how to upload and download blackberry application from webserver?

Tags: blackberry, webserver

Hi all how to upload and download blackberry application from webserver ? i have already set MIME type but yet i cant download sucessfully .so what can i do ?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. What MIME type did you set? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

In the application folder please find the install files in \deliverables\Web\ [version no]
From there take .jad file and all files with the extension of .cod file and deploy to the server.

And set the MIME type to the following.

JAD         text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

COD         application/vnd.rim.cod

Note : The usual problem may be we take .cod file from \deliverables\Standard\ [version no.] folder.  The .cod file find there **(in Standard folder)** is a zipped version of .cod files. If you are taking .cod file from there, you have to rename .cod file to .zip and take the multiple .cod from that.  Multiple .cod files created when your cod file is more than 64 KB.